# Prove divergence for improper integral of $y \sin(2/y)$

Tags: improper-integrals

How can I prove that the following improper integral diverge?

$$\int_e^\infty y \sin \left( \frac{2}{y} \right) \ dx$$

I think I'm supposed to separate it into two parts, but I don't know how to do it. Any input?

Comment: $x\sin(1/x)\to1$ as $x\to\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Put $$t=\frac 1x$$

Your integral has the same nature than
$$\int_0^1\frac 1t\sin(t)\frac{dt}{t^2}$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\sin(t)dt}{t^3}$$

but, near $ 0^+ $,

$$\frac{\sin(t)}{t^3}\sim \frac{1}{t^2}$$

and
$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t^2} \text{ diverges}$$

Comment: It's not clear for me how my integral has the same nature as the one you first describe, i.e.1/t*sin(t) dt/t^2. Can you develope this?

Comment: Look at the change of variable theorem for improper integrals.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "när 0+" sin(t) ~1/t^2?

Comment: @John_Average When $ t\to 0^+$ $\frac{\sin(t)}{t^3}\to \frac{1}{t^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand better. :)